# How can I print out an image tag to a Rails asset in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

How can I print out an image tag to a Rails asset in javascript?

If I have an image at /assets/images/my_image.png, the following will show an image in development, but not in a production.

`$('.myImage').html('<img src="/assets/images/my_image.png">');`

Comment: "/assets/my_image.png" doesn't work?

Comment: Nah - you can see the image asset missing here - http://www.dailydebate.co. If you click "agree" or "disagree" you should see the missing image icon.

Comment: other images in the app are working fine? whatis the value of `config.serve_static_assets` in prod.rb

Comment: `config.serve_static_assets = false`... so that sounds like a good thing to change. Does that hurt something else? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 1):

For heroku

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
```

also use

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) has good explanation you need to check out once.

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't seem to solve it. I'll move it into /public for now

Comment: `config.assets.compile = true` is set? which version of rails?

Comment: I see the image in your app now :)